# jQuery last append() or html() breaks sortable function

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, append, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a form that generates sortable divs. I am using .append() and .html() to add elements to these divs on button click.

This all works up to a certain point, the elements are added but the sortable function stops working.

In the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/edmCZ/4/  js section, if you scroll down to // Create Div - menuForm.html('...') is the one that breaks the sortable function. It works fine without this inclusion.

Please can anyone tell me why this is breaking the sortable function. I am using the Nested Sortable Plugin for this.

Thanks

Comment: For some reason when I took out the ul and li's from menuForm.html() it worked, no idea why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason when I took out the ul and li's from menuForm.html() it worked, no idea why though.